# Displaying CFQuery Result Over Time Span

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I'm able to get query's over a time span of say 1hr - in 15 minute increments...

I am just trying to stop displaying repetitive result when the Primary Key is the same.

ie: If something starts at 6:45am - and ends at 8:00am - I only want it to span the DIV once if the primary key (masterid) is the same.  And then if something else is at 8am with a different primary key - to span that div time frame etc...

I am contemplating a cfloop or the like - checking that the mastered is either the same or different/

Thoughts on how to do this...

Query code working fine - as is my display code... Image included to give idea of what I'm trying to do.

[image: Output]

```
    <cfloop index="incr" from="0" to="#loopreps#">
    <cfoutput>

    Loopreps is thru the time spans of 15 mins...

     <cfquery name="scht" datasource="#ds#">
 Proper Query
 </cfquery>

    <cfif scht.recordcount is not 0>
    <cfset mid = #scht.masterid#>
    This is where I am lost to hold it to only 1 result when spanning time


    Proper Display Across Div Height Span once if MasterID is same

    </cfif>

   </cfoutput>
   </cfloop>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are using CF for the task? You did not say which dbms you are using, but databases like SQL Server make this kind of task a lot easier. Without the need querying within a loop.

Comment: Site is all built in ColdFusion - the Database Integration is using Access

Comment: As a desktop database not designed for multi-threaded web apps, Access really limits your options. If it at all possible, upgrade to SQL Server. It is a lot more flexible and the express version is free. Having said that, you could still simplify it by having an auxiliary table containing the times, in fifteen minute increments. Simply JOIN your other table to it on the start/end time. The resulting query will contain all of the intervals you need. Then format query output however you need. (Edit) I used use a similar approach in SQL Server, before CTE's came alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually put a garbage value before starting a loop.

```
<cfset CompareValue = "value that will never occur in real life">
<cfloop>
<cfif FieldToCheck is not CompareValue>
<cfset CompareValue = FieldToCheck>
more code
<cfelse>
appropriate code, maybe nothing
</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: This is correct method - I just had another loop going on for the time population - I put the garbage value outside my other loop.   Thx.  Thx for insight also for other stuff - but Cold Fusion/Access has no trouble building/pulling times needed.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, as a desktop database, MS Access is rather limited. Enterprise databases like SQL Server offer much greater capabilities for tasks like this, such as [using CTE's](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

However, just to offer another perspective, you could also use an auxiliary table of times, instead. (That was a common approach in SQL Server, prior to the advent of CTE's). You could easily populate a table with fifteen minute increments, between `00:00` to `23:45`, using [Mark's loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572720/104223) as a basis.  Then simply JOIN to that table on the scheduled start and end times. (Access requires the extra parenthesis and derived table).

```
SELECT ti.IntervalTime
        , s.StartTime
        , s.EndTime
        , s.AppointmentName
FROM  TimeInterval ti LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT AppointmentName, StartTime, EndTime
            FROM   ScheduleTable 
            WHERE  ScheduleDate = <cfqueryparam value="#someDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">    
        ) s
        ON ( 
             ti.IntervalTime >= s.StartTime AND 
             ti.IntervalTime <= s.EndTime 
        )
WHERE ti.IntervalTime >= <cfqueryparam value="#fromTime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
AND   ti.IntervalTime <= <cfqueryparam value="#toTime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
ORDER BY ti.IntervalTime
```

The result will contain all of the intervals and appointments in one query, no need for looping. You can then output the results however you need.

```
IntervalTime | StartTime | EndTime  | Appointment Name
06:00:00     |           |          | 
06:15:00     |           |          | 
06:30:00     |           |          | 
06:45:00     | 06:45:00  | 08:00:00 | Edge 
07:00:00     | 06:45:00  | 08:00:00 | Edge 
07:15:00     | 06:45:00  | 08:00:00 | Edge 
07:30:00     | 06:45:00  | 08:00:00 | Edge 
....
```

Comment: Nicely detailed answer

Comment: My code gets me to this yes.  I am just trying to format to 1 result now and size the div appropriately.  SO I am not having trouble getting to the example above...

Comment: Yes, but using 50+ queries - *per request* - to do it is extremely inefficient. It will be a bottleneck if the application has more than a few users. It is far more efficient to run a single query. Then use the data to determine how many intervals an appointment spans. For example, a simple dateDiff("n") / 15 should tell you that.

Comment: Lost Leigh - as I have an Open and Close time - and break that into the 15min intervals - and in the intervals do a query to see if something is booked... Problem I was having was a span of say 4 intervals (1 hr) - and showing 4 things instead of 1... So that is sorted - but u've peaked my curiosity on reducing speed.  Not too worried as this only happens in an administration area... Perhaps I'll play with ur code in future... Thx

Comment: Well, there is no reason you could not incorporate Dan's suggestion , with the query above, and use it to determine when the loop hits a the start of a new appointment. Then simply calculate the number of intervals ie 4 using something like `int(dateDiff("n", StartTime, EndTime)/15)`. The exact sequence of the logic really depends on your current html/css though. Hard to be more specific without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over time increments directly using the CFLOOP tag.  For example this code outputs each 15 minutes.  You could combine a loop like this with a check (Q of a Q maybe) to extract availability.

```
<cfloop index="tm" from="8:00 AM" to="5:00 PM" step="#createTimespan(0,0,15,0)#">    
    <cfoutput> <li>#TimeFormat( tm, "h:mm TT" )#</li></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Just keep in mind this is an ok solution for short iterations. If doing long iterations I would set that "step"  attribute to a variable rather than calling a function directly. If *really* long I would probably choose something else. But for a couple days worth of increments it will work perfectly fine I think. See this post on [Interesting loop for date and time](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2008/10/17/cfloop.over.date.time). Good luck!

Comment: Having read the linked article, my initial impression was that using a variable instead of running createTimespan() each time through the loop should have sorted out the mentioned performance issues.